# Prove that $a,b>0$ and $a+b=1$ imply $a^{\frac{1}{(2a)^n}}+b^{\frac{1}{(2b)^n}}\leq 1$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, power-series, exponentiation, alternative-proof

Playing with exponent I found this :

> > Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ then we have :
> >     $$a^{\frac{1}{(2a)^n}}+b^{\frac{1}{(2b)^n}}\leq 1$$
> >     Where $n\geq 1$ a natural number .

First of all I have tested until $n=30$ . The equality cases are $a=b=0.5$ or $a=0$ and $b=1$ .

I have tried to invoke the convexity but it does not work .
For $n=1$ I can prove a part of the inequality using Bernoulli's inequality .I have tried to derivate but it's ugly .And finally I have make more progess using power series around $a=0.5$ .In fact we can approximate a part of the curve using parabolas .And after playing with exponent we see that we get an infinity of inequalities wich tend to $1$

So if you have a counter-example I accept or if you have an (the good) answer wich capt the truth of this.

Any helps is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Ps:Sorry for the bad english .

Edit :

### My proof :

Since we have a proof (see the link for Maximilian) of :

> > Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ an $n\geq 1$ a natural number then we have :
> >     $$a^{(2b)^n}+b^{(2a)^n}\leq 1$$

Let prove this :

> > Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ an $n\geq 1$ a natural number then we have :
> >     $$a^{\frac{1}{(2a)^n}}+b^{\frac{1}{(2b)^n}}\leq a^{(2b)^n}+b^{(2a)^n}\leq 1$$

The proof is very easy since we have :

$$a^{\frac{1}{(2a)^n}}\leq a^{(2b)^n}$$

Because it's equivalent to :

$$(4ab)^n\leq 1$$

Wich is true by Am-Gm and the condition $a+b=1$

Done !

My question: have you an alternative proof (using maybe convexity ?)

Ps:I think that Maximilian have seen that before me(it's a little bit mischievous ^^)

Comment: How do you come up with all of these?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I have been inspired by https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1029-242X-2013-468